# how to convert odata json to concrete DTO

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api2

I am attempting to take some ugly json, that looks like this:

[image]

And deserialize it to my DTO:

```
public class Account
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.etag")]
    public string etag { get; set; }
    public Guid accountid { get; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; }

}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
    public string context { get; set; }
    public List<Account> value { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I attempt to do it:

```
    public async Task<Account> GetAccount(string query)
    {
        var task = await Client.HTTPCLIENT.GetAsync(Client.HTTPCLIENT.BaseAddress + query);
        var jsonString = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
        return value.value.First();
    }
```

And my response partially works:

```
{"@odata.etag":"W/\"608578\"","accountid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","CreatedOn":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","OwnerId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","Name":"Smith","ModifiedOn":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","CreatedBy":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
```

**What am I doing wrong? How do I convert this odata json response to a c# object?**

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions that you don't specify:

- I assume you're using Json.net

For the date properties, you want to add the attribute [IsoDateTimeConverter], which comes with Json.net

So...

```
[IsoDateTimeConverter]
public DateTime CreatedOn { get; }
```

DateTime properties won't parse ISO 8601 strings by default, you have to use the converter.

And basically, that's your answer for the Guid's and such as well, except you also have to implement those converters for yourself.  You have to create a converter class, and read the input string, and parse it into the Guid object.  Then decorate each Guid property with a [YourCustomGuidConverter] attribute.

Comment: is there an easier way to do this than having to have those attributes? rather than using json.net maybe a different library?

Comment: I do custom parsing with SimpleJson as well, in some CSharp projects.
SimpleJson in general isn't as fully featured, and the main repository has some bugs that haven't been resolved.
But honestly, the customization isn't any easier in SimpleJson, just different.